# Large Annotation boxes on OAK-D

Tags: machine-learning, roboflow

Using Roboflow to train dataset.

Using OAK-D camera.

Dataset trained using Yolo v5.

Annotation boxes are as large as the screen but reading what the object is correct.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsLAY.jpg)

This is an example of one picture I used. For each pool ball/billiard ball I have over 20 images.

I’ve tried retraining in a different model.

I’ve also tweaked the confidence and overlap.

Nothing seems to work I’m sure I’m overlooking it any help would work.